# Dashed line in pgfplots not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Please look at this document:

https://www.overleaf.com/2201174ypzqyy

You can see that the bottom figure has a dashed line while the top does not, even though they both have `dashed` in their `addplot` options.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _Please look at this document_ 1361 lines? Sorry, no thank you. The problem should be reproducible with a _much_ smaller file; please reduce it to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and edit your question to include the code directly on this site.

Comment: 1300 of the lines are just points!

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron Yes, exactly, you can most likely eliminate 1298 of them and still show your problem

Comment: There, I reduced it to 59 lines. Please take a look now.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron Can you please copy it into this question? Having it on an external website means that any future visitors might not be able to see the same code. Remember, your questions aren't just for you, but for everyone else who comes to this website in the future as well

Comment: @percusse already nailed your problem. You are plotting them cyclically over and over. For example, use `line width=0.1pt` in the first plot, magnify the pdf, you will see what I mean.

Comment: @HarishKumar why does this problem not similarly manifest in the bottom plot, which has the exact same number of points in the exact same x-locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many data points that are too close to each other. So every line segment between each point is shorter than a dash. If you zoom hard on Acrobat you can see it. Here I've defined a much less dense pattern and you can see it clearly.

```
\addplot[draw=gray,dashed,dash pattern=on 0.1pt off 3mm] ....
```

[image]

The best thing would be to downsample your data. Because they are groups of five for some reason.

**EDIT**: It turns out that your curve is overparameterized and travels more than once on itself. So what I initially thought is not correct it's just overprinting but dashed still works. Here I've removed most of your data and it still gives the curve. Why the second one doesn't have the problem is because the curve length is very close to an integer multiple of the unit dash on/off length. Modify a few points and it will start aliasing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[draw=gray,dashed]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
0.0998334166468282  0.198669330795061\\
0.198669330795061   0.389418342308651\\
0.29552020666134    0.564642473395035\\
0.389418342308651   0.717356090899523\\
0.479425538604203   0.841470984807897\\
0.564642473395035   0.932039085967226\\
0.644217687237691   0.98544972998846\\
0.717356090899523   0.999573603041505\\
0.783326909627483   0.973847630878195\\
0.841470984807897   0.909297426825682\\
0.891207360061435   0.80849640381959\\
0.932039085967226   0.675463180551151\\
0.963558185417193   0.515501371821464\\
0.98544972998846    0.334988150155905\\
0.997494986604054   0.141120008059867\\
0.999573603041505   -0.0583741434275801\\
0.991664810452469   -0.255541102026832\\
0.973847630878195   -0.442520443294852\\
0.946300087687414   -0.611857890942719\\
0.909297426825682   -0.756802495307928\\
0.863209366648874   -0.871575772413588\\
0.80849640381959    -0.951602073889516\\
0.74570521217672    -0.993691003633465\\
0.675463180551151   -0.996164608835841\\
0.598472144103956   -0.958924274663138\\
0.515501371821464   -0.883454655720153\\
0.42737988023383    -0.772764487555987\\
0.334988150155905   -0.631266637872321\\
0.239249329213982   -0.464602179413757\\
0.141120008059867   -0.279415498198926\\
0.0415806624332905  -0.0830894028174964\\
-0.0583741434275801 0.116549204850494\\
-0.157745694143249  0.311541363513379\\
-0.255541102026832  0.494113351138609\\
-0.35078322768962   0.656986598718789\\
-0.442520443294852  0.793667863849153\\
-0.529836140908493  0.898708095811627\\
-0.611857890942719  0.967919672031487\\
-0.687766159183974  0.998543345374605\\
-0.756802495307928  0.989358246623382\\
-0.818277111064411  0.940730556679773\\
-0.871575772413588  0.854598908088281\\
-0.916165936749455  0.734397097874113\\
-0.951602073889516  0.584917192891762\\
-0.977530117665097  0.412118485241757\\
-0.993691003633465  0.222889914100246\\
-0.999923257564101  0.0247754254533578\\
-0.996164608835841  -0.174326781222981\\
-0.982452612624332  -0.366479129251928\\
-0.958924274663138  -0.54402111088937\\
-0.925814682327732  -0.699874687593544\\
-0.883454655720153  -0.827826469085654\\
-0.832267442223901  -0.922775421612807\\
-0.772764487555987  -0.980936230066492\\
-0.705540325570392  -0.999990206550703\\
-0.631266637872321  -0.979177729151317\\
-0.550685542597638  -0.919328525664676\\
-0.464602179413757  -0.822828594968708\\
-0.373876664830236  -0.693525084777122\\
-0.279415498198926  -0.536572918000435\\
-0.182162504272095  -0.358229282236827\\
-0.0830894028174964 -0.165604175448309\\
0.0168139004843506  0.0336230472211385\\
0.116549204850494   0.231509825101539\\
0.215119988087816   0.420167036826641\\
0.311541363513379   0.592073514707224\\
0.404849920616598   0.740375889952449\\
0.494113351138609   0.859161814856497\\
0.5784397643882 0.943695669444105\\
0.656986598718789   0.99060735569487\\
0.728969040125876   0.998026652716362\\
0.793667863849153   0.965657776549277\\
0.850436620628565   0.894791172140503\\
0.898708095811627   0.788252067375316\\
0.937999976774739   0.650287840157117\\
0.967919672031487   0.486398688853798\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm a bit confused though: the bottom plot has exactly the same number of points that are placed in exactly the same spots on the x-axis. So why is the problem only appearing in the upper plot?

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron I guess they are not ordered properly so it is aliasing.

Comment: You are a handsome man

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.